Avatar doesn't appear because of methods
I am trying to remake something at my old code (flutter) and I receive an issue at data["avatarUrl"] and I don't understand why because I also initiate imagePicker and getData() method ,getSocialData() and still receive this red line... what I should change to my code? How I can make the photo the user adds to appear
class NewUserPage extends StatefulWidget {
  late ScrollController scrollController;

  NewUserPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<NewUserPage> createState() => NewUserProfile();
}

class NewUserProfile extends State<NewUserPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool isFileImage = false;
  late User user;
  late File pickedFile;
  String? userImage;
  String? address;
  String? precise_address;
  String? userName;
  String? facebookUrl;
  String? instagramUrl;
  String? tikTokUrl;
  TextEditingController facebookController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController instagramController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController tiktokController = TextEditingController();
  late String userId;
  Random randomGenerator = Random();

  String? searchString;
  String? country;
  QuerySnapshot? querySnapshot;
  Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map>>? stream;
  TabController? tabController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    tabController = TabController(
      length: 3,
      vsync: this,
    );
    tabController?.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    initUser();
  }

  final Algolia _algoliaApp = AlgoliaApplication.algolia;

  String? serviveProvideId;
  Future<List<AlgoliaObjectSnapshot>> _operation(String input) async {
    AlgoliaQuery query = _algoliaApp.instance.index("users").search(input);
    AlgoliaQuerySnapshot querySnap = await query.getObjects();
    List<AlgoliaObjectSnapshot> results = querySnap.hits;
    return results;
  }

  Future<void> displayPrediction(Prediction p, BuildContext context) async {
    var placeId = p.placeId;
    var address = await FlGeocoder(Constants.googlePlaceKey)
        .findAddressesFromPlaceId(placeId!);
    setState(() {
      searchString = p.description!;
    });
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(userId).update({
      "precise_location": searchString,
    });
    country = address.first.country!.longName;
  }

  initUser() async {
    user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
    userId = user.uid;
    logger.e("user id at init user =$userId");
    getSocialData();
    getData();
  }

  final TextEditingController _userNameController = TextEditingController();

  late File _image;
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  Future getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (pickedFile != null) {
      setState(() {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
      });
      Reference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
      Uint8List imageData = _image.readAsBytesSync();
      storageReference
          .child("Users Profile")
          .child(userId)
          .putData(imageData)
          .then((uploadTask) async {
        var dowurl = await uploadTask.ref.getDownloadURL();
        String url = dowurl.toString();

        Map<String, dynamic> urlNull = {
          'avatarUrl': url,
        };
        DocumentReference prereference =
            FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(userId);

        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
          transaction.update(prereference, urlNull);
        });
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Container(
                  child: ListView(children: [
                SizedBox(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.32,
                    child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0),
                        child: Container(
                          width: 80,
                          height: 80,
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundImage: const AssetImage(
                                'assets/images/profilepic.png'),
                            child: Image.network(data["avatarUrl"]),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                          top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.09,
                          left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.09,
                          child: Row(children: [
                            Positioned(
                                right: 24,
                                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.12,
                                child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                                  Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
                                      child: Row(children: [
                                        Column(
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                                CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                            children: [
                                              SizedBox(
                                                width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                        .size
                                                        .width -
                                                    40,
                                                child: Text("$userName",
                                                    overflow:
                                                        TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                    maxLines: 3,
                                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.black,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.bold,
                                                      fontSize: 20,
                                                    )),
                                              ),
                                              const SizedBox(
                                                height: 5,
                                              ),
                                              Row(
                                                children: [
                                                  Icon(
                                                    Icons.location_pin,
                                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                                    size: 18,
                                                  ),
                                                  Text(
                                                    address == "default"
                                                        ? "Location not added"
                                                        : address ?? "",
                                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                                      fontSize: 14,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                height: 5,
                                              ),
                                              Row(
                                                children: [
                                                  Icon(Icons.calendar_month,
                                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                                      size: 18)
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                height: 13,
                                              ),
                                              ButtonTheme(
                                                  minWidth: 40.0,
                                                  height: 20.0,
                                                  buttonColor: Colors.black,
                                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                      borderRadius:
                                                          BorderRadius.circular(
                                                              30.0)),
                                                  child: ElevatedButton(
                                                      style: ElevatedButton
                                                          .styleFrom(
                                                              backgroundColor:
                                                                  Colors.black),
                                                      child: const Text(
                                                        "Edit",
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                            color:
                                                                Colors.white),
                                                      ),
                                                      onPressed: () {
                                                        instagramController
                                                                .text =
                                                            instagramUrl ?? "";
                                                        tiktokController.text =
                                                            tikTokUrl ?? "";
                                                        facebookController
                                                                .text =
                                                            facebookUrl ?? "";
                                                        _userEditBottomSheet(
                                                            context);
                                                      }))
                                            ])
                                      ]))
                                ]))
                          ]))
                    ]))
              ])))),
    );
  }

  void _userEditBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext bc) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .90,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, top: 15.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        const Text("Schimba nume profil"),
                        const Spacer(),
                        IconButton(
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.cancel),
                          color: Colors.orange,
                          iconSize: 25,
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                            child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0),
                          child: TextField(
                            controller: _userNameController,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              helperText: "username",
                            ),
                          ),
                        )),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ElevatedButton(
                            child: const Text('Salveaza nume'),
                            onPressed: () async {
                              String userName = _userNameController.text;
                              Map<String, dynamic> data = {
                                'name': userName,
                              };
                              DocumentReference reference = FirebaseFirestore
                                  .instance
                                  .collection('Users')
                                  .doc(userId);

                              FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                  .runTransaction((transaction) async {
                                transaction.update(reference, data);
                              });

                              //                            final uid =
                              //                                await Provider.of(context).auth.getCurrentUID();
                              //                            await Provider.of(context)
                              //                                .db
                              //                                .collection('Users')
                              //                                .document('${user.uid}')
                              //                                .setData(userr.toJson());
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            })
                      ],
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Image.asset(
                            'assets/images/tiktok.png',
                            width: 50,
                            height: 50,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            width: 5,
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: TextField(
                              controller: tiktokController,
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: "Paste your link here"),
                              onChanged: (str) {
                                FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                    .collection('Users')
                                    .doc(userId)
                                    .collection('Social')
                                    .doc('detail')
                                    .set({"tiktok": str},
                                        SetOptions(merge: true));
                              },
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Image.asset(
                            'assets/images/instagram.png',
                            width: 50,
                            height: 50,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            width: 5,
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: TextField(
                              controller: instagramController,
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: "Paste your link here"),
                              onChanged: (str) {
                                FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                    .collection('Users')
                                    .doc(userId)
                                    .collection('Social')
                                    .doc('detail')
                                    .set({"instagram": str},
                                        SetOptions(merge: true));
                              },
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Image.asset(
                            'assets/images/facebook.png',
                            width: 50,
                            height: 50,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            width: 5,
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: TextField(
                              controller: facebookController,
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: "Paste your link here"),
                              onChanged: (str) {
                                FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                    .collection('Users')
                                    .doc(userId)
                                    .collection('Social')
                                    .doc('detail')
                                    .set({"facebook": str},
                                        SetOptions(merge: true));
                              },
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                            child: Image.asset(
                              'assets/images/googlemap.png',
                              width: 50,
                              height: 50,
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            width: 5,
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: TextField(
                              onTap: () async {
                                Prediction? p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
                                    context: context,
                                    apiKey:
                                        "AIzaSyCZxFbtd3_eLDW_JtLmtJh1yv8u5AHa_Bk",
                                    mode: Mode.overlay, // Mode.fullscreen
                                    hint: 'Search location');
                                await displayPrediction(p!, context);
                                Navigator.pop(context);
                                _userEditBottomSheet(context);
                              },
                              controller: TextEditingController()
                                ..text = searchString ?? "",
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: "Add a precise location"),
                              onChanged: (str) {
                                // FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                //     .collection('Users')
                                //     .document('$userId')
                                //     .setData({"facebook": str}, merge: true);
                              },
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                          ),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                          textStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          getImage();
                        },
                        child: const Text("Adauga poza profil"))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  void getData() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Users")
        .doc(userId)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((event) {
      setState(() {
        userImage = (event.data() as Map)['avatarUrl'] ?? "";
        address = (event.data() as Map)['address'] ?? "";
        precise_address = (event.data() as Map)['precise_location'] ?? "";
        userName = (event.data() as Map)['name'] ?? "";
      });
    });
  }

  void getSocialData() {
    DocumentReference reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(userId)
        .collection('Social')
        .doc('detail');
    print(reference.path);
    reference.snapshots().listen((event) {
      setState(() {
        facebookUrl =
            event.data() == null ? null : (event.data() as Map)['facebook'];
        instagramUrl =
            event.data() == null ? null : (event.data() as Map)['instagram'];
        tikTokUrl =
            event.data() == null ? null : (event.data() as Map)['tiktok'];
      });
    });
  }

  Future<void> _launchUrl(String url, BuildContext context) async {
    if (url.isEmpty) {
      await Alert(
        context: context,
        type: AlertType.warning,
        title: "Social Link error",
        desc: "You have not provided social link",
        buttons: [
          DialogButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            color: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 179, 134, 1.0),
            child: const Text(
              "Close",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ).show();
    } else {
      if (await canLaunch(url)) {
        await launch(url);
      } else {
        await Alert(
          context: context,
          type: AlertType.warning,
          title: "Social Link error",
          desc: "Cannot Launch Url",
          buttons: [
            DialogButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              color: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 179, 134, 1.0),
              child: const Text(
                "Close",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ).show();
      }
    }
  }
}

enum uploadTypes {
  GALLERY,
  STORY,
  VIDEO,
  IMAGE,
}

Text _buildRatingStars(int rating) {
  String stars = '';
  for (int i = 0; i < rating; i++) {
    stars += '⭐ ';
  }
  stars.trim();
  return Text(stars);
}

